# Check if DIV is hidden using IF ELSE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a JQUERY to toggle the visibility of a DIV, this works fine, however I need to resize my page at the same time but VSE2012 is underlining some of the curly brackets saying ')' expected and saying syntax error for the 'else'. Here is my code:

```
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("p").click(function () {
         $("#teamtables").toggle(); 
         If ( $("#teamtables").is(":visible") ) {
             $('.mPage').css({ "height": "2600px" });
         } else {
             $('.mPage').css({ "height": "700px" });
        }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript is a case-sensitive language. You want to write `if`, not `If`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP has made a small typo error `If` should be `if`


Comment: Your script tags are also vague.  It's not the problem, but it's *a* problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, change `If` to `if`
Try this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("p").click(function () {
         $("#teamtables").toggle(); 
         if ( $("#teamtables").is(":visible") ) {
             $('.mPage').css({ "height": "2600px" });
         } else {
             $('.mPage').css({ "height": "700px" });
        }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, rookie mistake, it's working now, cheers.

Comment: glad to help you, accept the answer when you can to help other guys with your same problem @user2096512